# How to prioritize queries from different user roles in superset?

Tags: apache-superset

I have *low-priority* users and *high-priority* users. First of all, I need to process queries from *high-priority* users. *Low-priority* users should be limited initially because they slow down the *high-priority* users.

At the moment I have not found a solution. Is this generally possible or do I need to fork *apache-superset* and implement such logic myself in the source code? Is this functionality planned in the roadmap?

Answer (score 0):

Superset generally is a thin layer over your existing data stores and doesn't have much of a compute layer.

With this in mind, the right technical decision is probably to configure this at the database / data store layer. Many people integrate LDAP both into Superset and into their data store so 2-way configuration of roles & datas tore priorities / permissions can be configured.

With that being said, Superset is open source! You're definitely welcome to fork the code and implement it yourself. Better yet, you can feel free to raise a discussion by creating a Github issue.

Answer (score 0):

Like Srini said, it depends on your data layer.

One way you could this is by defining a custom `SQL_QUERY_MUTATOR` in your `superset_config.py`:

```py
# superset_config.py
def SQL_QUERY_MUTATOR(sql, username, security_manager):
    pool = "vip" if username in VIP_LIST else "normal"
    return f"-- pool: {pool}\n{sql}"
```

This will prepend a comment to the query specifying a pool that's either "vip" or "normal". You could then send this to a proxy that parses the comment and dispatches the query to the proper header.

Another way of doing this is specifying a `DB_CONNECTION_MUTATOR` that sets connection parameters depending on the user:

```py
# superset_config.py
def DB_CONNECTION_MUTATOR(uri, params, username, security_manager, source):
    pool = "vip" if username in VIP_LIST else "normal"
    params["configuration"] = {"job.queue.name": pool}}
    return uri, params
```